# Appending text to a RichText item ("Body") is resulting in TWO Body items...why?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

An email arrives into a mail-in database.  I look at it and see that it has a single Body item, which is Rich Text.

In an agent run after new mail arrives, I want to update the arriving memo, and append some text to that Body item and then save it.   I use getfirstitem to get a handle on it, and then use AddNewLine and Appendtext in successive lines of code, adding a bit of text to it, before saving it.

After this is done, I look at the backend document again and where there used to be a single Body item there are now two.  Each has a portion of what I expected a single item to have.  Between the two, nothing is missing.

Note:   The incoming email also has attachments...but it did originally before I updated it and again, there was only one Body item.

Note2:  Sending the email from Outlook.  How that could be related I don't know.

What could be causing this or what might I do to work around this.  Open to all suggestions/ideas.

Thank you

Matt Smith

Comment: A document can have lots of Body fields, that's perfectly normal.  Body is also a RichTextField which behaves very differently from a plain text field, so just getting the item and appending to its value doesn't work the same way.  I suggest you read up on the NotesRichText class.

Comment: I am aware that a document can have multiple body items (and other fields as well) but I am trying to get a handle on just the ONE existing item and edit it....instead of causing it to result in multiple items.    I just reviewed all of the help on the NotesRichTextItem and see nothing to clue me in on what is causing this.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need it to remain just one Body item. Notes has 30 years of programming behind its APIs geared toward presenting a single logical rich text item while optimizing its internal operation by splitting it into multiple physical items. Maybe it's optimal, or maybe it's not, but you'd have to go down to low-level C API code in order to try and control it.

Comment: From what the Help says, in order to get a handle on an existing Rich Text item, you use 'getfirstitem' and that proramatically you can only access the first of any multiple items of the same name.    Since I want to append text to the bottom of everything, I was hoping to have only one so I could use 'appendtext'.

However, I rewrote everything to handle my task a different way and found another way of going about what I wanted to accomplish.   For that reason I am going to mark this solved, but it is still a curiosity why it was doing what it was doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `Compact` on the Body after you've finished adding to it (and before saving if you do an explicit save), that might reduce it to a single item, but it's not guaranteed.

There are cases where Body is forced to be 2 or more items. E.g.:

- If an email comes in as MIME (which is common for emails from outside your network), each MIME part is always a separate Body item, and there are normally 2 or more MIME parts for a single email.
- I think each rich-text item has a strict 64 kB size limit for the raw data, so content exceeding 64 kB will always be 2 or more items, but I'm not sure of this.

As others have said in comments, it's normal to have more than 1 item for rich-text content. You should never have to care about this. If you use `GetFirstItem` to get a rich-text item and add text to the end of it, it will act like one item from an end-user perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I decided on another way to accomplish what i needed, not appending text, so this question is no longer in need of help, other than to sate my own curiosity.  Thanks guys.